# Loop through Access database and perform basic operations using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have been performing these operations through excel, but the raw data that I am dealing with is overwhelming for excel. I shifted over to access as the database but I am trying to find similar functionality. I am still using excel as my interface.

I am essintially breaking my data into samples. Taking a sample of the data, analyzing it then moving on to the next sample. I would like to do the same with the Access data. What I am looking for is how to perform operations (summation, multipication, division,max, min...) on a sample using a for loop. Also, what is the ID of max value and ID on the min value. I am also dealing with a huge amout of raw data, so the less lines of code would be optimal. Any pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Code in Excel:

```
For CoUnTer = 1 To FindRecordCount

        Set Circ_Rng = WS.Range(WS.Cells(CoUnTer , 5), WS.Cells(CoUnTer  + TempTimeFrame - 1, 5))
        Set DataPoint_Rng = WS.Range(WS.Cells(CoUnTer , 1), WS.Cells(CoUnTer  + TempTimeFrame - 1, 1))
        Set DataPoint_Circ_Rng = WS.Range(WS.Cells(CoUnTer , 8), WS.Cells(CoUnTer  + TempTimeFrame - 1, 8))
        Set DataPoint_SQ_Rng = WS.Range(WS.Cells(CoUnTer , 9), WS.Cells(CoUnTer  + TempTimeFrame - 1, 9))
        '---------------------------
        MaxPoint = WorksheetFunction.Max(CircPressure_Rng)
        Row_At_MaxPressure = WS.Columns(5).Cells.Find(MaxPoint, After:=WS.Cells(3, 5), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext).Row

    Sigma_X_Sigma_Y = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Circ_Rng) * WorksheetFunction.Sum(DataPoint_Rng)
    Sigma_XY = WorksheetFunction.Sum(DataPoint_Circ_Rng)
    Sigma_X2 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(DataPoint_SQ_Rng)
    Min_X = WorksheetFunction.Min(DataPoint_Rng)
```

Code for Access data:
This code gets the data sample. What I am missing how can I handle the operations on them similar to what I have done in excel.

```
Sub GetAccessData()


Dim DBFullName As String
Dim Connect As String, Source As String
Dim Connection As ADODB.Connection
Dim Recordset As ADODB.Recordset
Dim Col As Long
Dim x As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'DataBase Path
DBFullName = WB_Path & "\RawData - Template.accdb"

'Open the Connection
Set Connection = New ADODB.Connection
Connect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"
Connect = Connect & "Data Source=" & DBFullName & ";"
Connection.Open ConnectionString:=Connect

'Create a RecordSet
Set Recordset = New ADODB.Recordset
' Client-side cursor
Recordset.CursorLocation = adUseClient

With Recordset
    Source = "SELECT * FROM  RawData WHERE [ID] BETWEEN " & StartofData & " AND " & EndofData
    .Open Source:=Source, ActiveConnection:=Connection
    On Error Resume Next

End With
EndofData = Recordset.RecordCount

Set Recordset = Nothing
Connection.Close
Set Connection = Nothing
'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are seeing, Excel is better for some things and Access is better for some things.  Sometimes you can literally substitute Access for Excel, and vice versa, but often each one should be used for it's intended purpose.  There are probably a few ways forward here, but I would lean towards leaving your Excel stuff in Excel, and control Excel from Access.  You can use Late Binding or Early Binding to control one app from another app.  Here are two options for you to consider.

```
‘EARLY BINDING
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit ' Use this to make sure your variables are defined

' One way to be able to use these objects throughout the Module is to Declare them
' Here and not in a Sub

Private objExcel As Excel.Application
Private xlWB As Excel.Workbook
Private xlWS As Excel.Worksheet

Sub Rep()

Dim strFile As String

strFile = "C:\your_path_here\YourExcelFile.xls"

' Opens Excel and makes it Visible
Set objExcel = New Excel.Application
objExcel.Visible = True

'Opens up the Workbook
Set xlWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFile)

'Sets the Workseet to the last active sheet - Better to use the commented version and use the name of the sheet.
Set xlWS = xlWB.ActiveSheet
'Set xlWS = xlWB("Sheet2")

With xlWS ' You are now working with the Named file and the named worksheet


End With

'Do Close and Cleanup
End Sub


 
‘LATE BINDING
Sub ControlExcelFromAccess()

' No reference to a type library is needed to use late binding.
' As long as the object supports IDispatch, the method can
' be dynamically located and invoked at run-time.

' Declare the object as a late-bound object
  Dim oExcel As Object
  Dim strFile As String

  strFile = "C:\your_path_here\YourExcelFile.xls"

  Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

' The Visible property is called via IDispatch
  oExcel.Visible = True

  Set xlWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFile)

'Call code here . . .

Set oExcel = Nothing

End Sub
```

Just copy/paste your code inside this code, make a few small tweaks if necessary, and you should be good to go!